# Why I get error "No such interface supported" in Web synchronisation SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, websync

I have a error during my web synchronisation SQL server, I get the error "No such interface supported" during my SQL server express 2014 (32 bits) synchronise the SQL server 2016(64 bits). I enable the 32 bit in the application pool. The subscription is created in the server and in the local computer. Do you have an idea what happened with my application c#. But, I use only the websync.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is a patch if you are having this error specifically: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014719/fix-0x80004002-no-such-interface-supported-error-when-you-use-rmo-to-r

Comment: yess, it's that. I received this error when I add the information for the web server in the MergeSynchronizationAgent